# Googlebot Desktop detected as mobile

Tags: mobile, media-queries, desktop, googlebot

I am migrating a desktop site to support mobile through a separate set of urls. At the root of the site, I am using media queries to detect if user is mobile or desktop and then redirect to the appropriate area.

For some reason,  the desktop Googlebot (using Google Search Console's 'Fetch as Google')  is coming through as mobile.  It is being detected as mobile based on the following media query...

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {  ... }
```

I was able to determine that the viewport width/height was 1024 x 768.  So, the Googlebot desktop is coming through using tablet sizes.

When using the "Fetch as Google" as Smartphone, then it comes through as 980 x 1743.  This is correctly detected as mobile based on the media query...

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
```

What gives?  Do I need to put in special user agent checking just for Googlebot to detect desktop or mobile?

Any better method of detecting mobile or desktop that would work properly with Googlebot?  Prefer not to have to resort to check the 1000 possible strings of different mobile device user agents. The media query check has worked pretty well with real devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `orientation` query:

```css
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  p {
    color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Resize to change color</p>
</body>
```